# Loopback embedsMany Helper methods don't work

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have these two models:

**Student**

```
{
    "name": "student",
    "plural": "students",
    "base": "User",
    "idInjection": false,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "relations": {
        "test": {
            "type": "embedsMany",
            "model": "test",
            "property": "mytest",
            "options": {
                "validate": true,
                "forceId": false
            }
    }
}
```

and

**Test**

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "base": "Model",
    "idInjection": true,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "text": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to create a new test I get this error

`Error: Invalid reference: undefined`

I create the test in this way:

**Student.js**

```
studentInstance.test.add({text : "something "})
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

Delete in embedsMany

update id in test.

**Student.js**

```
Student.show = function(email, cb) {


        Student.findById(email,function(err, student) {

            ...

            var tmp = student.mytest;

            for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                student.test.destroy(tmp[i].id);
            }

        })

               ...

    }
```

I tried with

`destroy` not work correctly, not always remove the data

and

`remove`   show this error

```
Error: Invalid reference: undefined
    at EmbedsMany.remove
```

**Update**

Added a example of db

```
{
    "_id": "value",
    "property1": "value",
    .
    .

    "mytest": [
        {
            "text": "something",
            "creation": {
                "$date": "2016-08-23T14:31:44.678Z"
            },
            "id": "d738253472876b17feb4b46b"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have `test` model.

In `test.json` you defined its names as `notification` => `"name": "notification",`

**UPDATE**

For building (without persisting) an embedded instance please use `studentInstance.test.build({text : "something "})`

and for creating (with persisting) that please use `studentInstance.test.create({text : "something "})`

Comment: Thanks for answer. isn't this the error . I have wrong the copy/paste . In the project the names are ok.

Comment: Thanks this work. Now I have the same problem for delete a test I tried with `remove` , `unset` and `destroyById`

Comment: @Phan Because your embedded model does not have id (`idInection`), you can't use `destroyById`. You need to do manually (like a normal object) or add id to embedded model

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I have again problem with the delete. I updated the question.

Comment: @Phan `destroy` and `destroyById` is the same for `embedsMany`. Did your embedded instances have `id` in db?

Comment: Yes . I updated the question with a example of my db

Comment: @Phan So `destroyById` should work. You can see all functions by printing `app.models.Student.prototype`

Answer (score 0):

After 3 years, I've faced with same problem by using `remove, destroyById`.

And then I use `unset` method. It works.

```
Person.findById(body.metadata.person.id, (err, person) => {
    person.creditCards.unset(
        body.creditCard.id,
        (err, res) => {
        }
    );
}
```

This works well.